# Regex: Deleting duplicate spaces with re.sub returns commas after all characters

Tags: python, regex

There might be an easy fix for this, but I cannot find it. I am trying to delete duplicate spaces in a string (a sentence really).

This is the sentence:
'Kan me      niks voorstellen     bij dat   verhaal, want'

And this is the code I'm using. When I run this, it returns the sentence without the extra spaces, but with a comma after each character:

K,a,n, ,m,e, ,n,i,k,s, ,v,o,o,r,s,t,e,l,l,e,n, ,b,i,j, ,d,a,t, ,v,e,r,h,a,a,l, ,w,a,n,t

Could this be due to the fact that I'm writing to a csv file? Thanks for your help!

```
import csv, re
with open('spaties.csv', 'r', newline='') as readFile:
    reader = csv.reader(readFile)

    with open('spaties2.csv', 'w', newline='') as new_file:
        writer = csv.writer(new_file)

        for line in reader:
            writer.writerow(line)
            st = ''.join(line)
            print(st)
            st = re.sub("\s\s+", " ", st.strip())
            print(st)
            writer.writerow(st)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `re.sub` is fine, the issue is with `csv.writer`:

`writerow` expects an **iterable of strings**, so it is iterating over the characters of the srting and considering each character a different column. If you just want to write the text as-is write to the file directly and do not use `csv.writer`.

You probably want to call `re.sub` on each element as in:

```
for line in reader:
    writer.writerow(line)
    st = [re.sub("\s+", " ", x) for x in line]
    writer.writerow(st)
```

Or you have to split the line after calling `re.sub`:

```
for line in reader:
    writer.writerow(line)
    st = ','.join(line)
    st = re.sub("\s+", " ", st)
    # note: if the columns contain "," this might not produce the
    # result you want!
    writer.writerow(st.split(','))
```

Comment: thanks! the code works the way I want using your first option.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to strip all extra whitespace, newlines, tabs etc from a string you can use:

```
s = 'Kan me     niks voorstellen   bij dat verhaal, want'
s = " ".join(s.split())

print(s)
```

Output:

```
Kan me niks voorstellen bij dat verhaal, want
```

Comment: He wants to remove extra spaces from csv columns. This would put all lines of the csv file into a single line. Using `re.sub` is probably also faster and uses less memory since it does not have to create a temporary list.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Sorry for the confusion.